# MySQL Replication: Insert generating VERY huge temporary tables

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, myisam

our replication slave is generating ~300GB temporary files while running relatively simple inserts.

**Our setup:**
Master: 5.0.45-0.sles10.x86_64,

Slave: 5.0.85-win32, also tried with 5.1.57-win64, same DB

**Slave configuration:**

> max_connections=100
>   query_cache_size=1M
>   table_cache=2048
>   tmp_table_size=32M
>   thread_cache_size=8
>   binlog_cache_size = 10M
>   myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
>   myisam_sort_buffer_size=69M
>   key_buffer_size=55M
>   read_buffer_size=64K
>   read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
>   sort_buffer_size=8M
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=16M
>   innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
>   innodb_log_buffer_size=16M
>   innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
>   innodb_thread_concurrency=10
>   datadir=D:\MySQLrepl\
>   innodb_data_home_dir=D:\MySQLrepl\
>   innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:33266M;ibdata2:31484M;ibdata3:52988M;ibdata4:123492M;ibdata5:100M:autoextend
>   innodb_log_group_home_dir=D:\MySQLrepl\
>   innodb_log_files_in_group=2
>   innodb_log_file_size=128M
>   log-bin=mysql-bin

**Database information:**
~360 GB total data size
~50 GB data size for affected database, rest in different database
Storage engine is innoDB for all tables
Database was transfered to slave with MySQL Enterprise Backup 3.5.2
sernumbers_results contains around 317 million rows, size is around 17,7 GB, rowid is the primary key.

**One of the queries generating the problem:**

> INSERT INTO sernumbers_results_2009 SELECT * FROM sernumbers_results WHERE rowid>(SELECT rowid FROM sernumbers_results_2009 order by rowid desc limit 1) ORDER BY rowid LIMIT 10000

What this should do, according to my colleagues logic, is to copy results from 2009 to a separate table bit by bit. He has a good excuse for this, he is french ;)
He also says that running the insert queries was fast on the server and indeed: the SELECT-part from that query runs in 0.18s without any problems, so it seems that there is a problem with the insert bit. It seems that all databases are converted to temporary MyISAM-tables before the query is applied. It also seems that there is little to none back-conversion because the server is starting with the next temporary table almost immediately when the one before has reached it's maximum size.

**I'm really totally clueless here, so any help or suggestion is really appreciated.**

Answer (score 4):

Algorithmically, it is doing what your colleague says. But, do you see what it is doing ???

It is generating 10,000 temp tables each containing 1 row after traversing 317 million rows through in the InnoDB internal index. Each temp table is a complete regeneration of the rowids in sernumbers_results_2009 table along with executing handler_read_prev commands internally to sort the data by an index scan from the back of the internal rowid index. Also, please remember you are dealing with InnoDB. Who knows what [Multiversioning (via MVCC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) is going on so that the INSERT is completed without interference and with rollback capabilities.

Is there any reason why this query wouldn't work for you ???

```
INSERT INTO sernumbers_results_2009
SELECT * FROM sernumbers_results
ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 10000;
```

This will definitely generate one temp table.

Give it a Try !!!